# Geth remote access to another computer for Websocket

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to connect to a different machine remotely for the node server I run windows server, but I don't know what to do.

ı want use Websocket use for connect : WS://SERVERIP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether the websocket is available or not is dependent on a few things:

1. What options are used when running the geth command to run your node on the server. You should use the flags below to define that geth should use a websocket and define the address and port where it should be available.

```
  --ws                                Enable the WS-RPC server
  --ws.addr value                     WS-RPC server listening interface (default: "localhost")
  --ws.port value                     WS-RPC server listening port (default: 8546)
  --ws.api value                      API's offered over the WS-RPC interface
  --ws.origins value                  Origins from which to accept websockets requests
```

2. You should make sure the port that you select is not blocked by your firewall and is open to the outside world.

**Warning**: If you are opening your node to the outside world, you are potentially opening  yourself up to risk. You'll want to check that you are **not using any unlocked accounts** with value. You may also want to add specific origins that you want to allow and make sure your firewalls are conf

Comment: geth --cache 4096 --rpc --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcport "8545" --rpcapi "db, eth, net, web3, personal" --ws --wsport 8546 --wsaddr "127.0.0.1" --wsorigins "*" --wsapi "web3, eth" --maxpeers=100  I use this code to provide a node connection, but I cannot access it from any machine from the outside.I have permissions through the firewall ports opening.only ı use windows firewall

Comment: You need to add a wild card in `--wsorigins '*'` to allow from anywhere rather than an empty string- Note: this is not this most secure option - you'd be better to list where you are connecting from.